# Is the saturation magnetization of a thin film different if you apply the field at different directions?

Tags: condensed-matter, magnetic-fields, solid-state-physics, measurements, magnetic-moment

I'm getting different values of the saturation magnetization when I measure them in-plane versus out of plane. The saturation magnetization for the out of plane measurement is greater than in the in plane measurement. The film has perpendicular magnetic anisotropy and I am wondering if this could be the reason for the difference in magnetization values at saturation.

From a domain perspective, I also wonder if the high aspect ratio of the film (the area is much larger compared to the thickness) also contributes to this.

Comment: Most thin films have in-plane anisotropy. Atoms are little bar magnets, and they tend to line up. TbFe2 is one of the few that have perpendicular anistropy. I have forgotten a lot, but I believe it has a high saturation magnetization in one orientation. It divides into domains of up and down. To saturate up, the up domain must grow. For that to happen, the domain wall must move. The domain walls get pinned, which makes it difficult to move. But you should check that before believing it.

Comment: It is most obvious since the susceptibility of any material is in general a tensor, not a scalar. Thus magnetisation must and will depend on directions unless there is a symmetry in the system.